# NMinimize and DE

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to use the **Differential Evolution** option of `NMinimize` to find the "optimal" solution for the hyper-sphere function defined as follows,

```
f[1] = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x^2]];
```

The input for the function is a vector of *D* real-valued components that are constrained by -100 and 100.

Is it possible to solve this (or similar) problem using `NMinimize`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think it is. Of course, as I read the problem, the minimum is `0.` and the use of `NMinimize` is unnecessary. (Perhaps more detail, or a nontrivial example, would help you get more help, if this comment is unsatisfactory.)

Comment: Example: `Block[{f, d = 99, vars, x},
 vars = Array[x, d];
 f[1] = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x^2], RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, "WarningMessages" -> False}];
 NMinimize[{f[1][vars], Thread[-100 < vars < 100]}, vars,
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
 ]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I agree the Sphere function is trivial but I just wanted to know how to use ```NMinimize``` with vectors and you have explained to me. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. This is pretty much the same problem, with a variation on the solution: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125379/how-to-find-global-minimum-of-function-depending-on-list